# Connection default not found using TypeORM in a class

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

I am trying to use TypeORM inside a class but for some reason it can not find the default connection, I am awaiting the connection and I am sure that the config is right because I tested it with .then() and that did work

```
class App {
    public app: express.Application;

    constructor() {
        this.app = express();
        this.connect();
        this.test();
        this.config();
        this.routes();
    }

    private async connect(): Promise<Connection> {
        return createConnection();
    }

    private async test(): Promise<User> {
        const repository = getRepository(User);
        const user = new User();
        user.firstName = 'Daniell';
        user.lastName = 'lastname';
        return repository.save(user);
    }
```

I call the class like

```
import App from './App';
import { Server } from './Server';

(() => new Server(App))();
```

Why can it not find the default connection?

Comment: What does the `Server` constructor do? Currently it seems like you just pass it the reference to `App` class instead of instantiating it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the class like

```
class App {
    public app: express.Application;
    private connection: Promise<Connection>;

    constructor() {
        this.connection = createConnection();
        this.config();
    }

    private async config(): Promise<void> {
        // Load TypeORM with ormconfig.json options
        await this.connection;
```